# Can't connect from EC2 PHP to cloud MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb

I am trying to connect from my PHP running on EC2 to newly created MongoDB free cloud cluster.
MongoDB installed:

```
sudo pecl install mongodb
```

And extension appear in php.ini:
[image]

My code:

```
<?php
echo "start";
echo(MONGODB_VERSION);
try
{
$client = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager(
    'mongodb://user:password@cluster0-shard-00-00-tmugt.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-tmugt.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-tmugt.mongodb.net:27017/testDB?ssl=true&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&w=majority');
echo("<br>Client created");
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
    echo "***Client failed*** " . $e->getMessage();
    exit();
}

echo("<br>");
var_dump($client);
echo("<br>");
var_dump(bin2hex(\MongoDB\BSON\fromPHP(['x'=>1])));
var_dump(class_exists('MongoDB\Driver\Manager'));

try{
    $db = $client->selectDB("testDB");
    echo("<db>Database selected");
}
catch(MongoConnectionException $e)
{
    echo '<p>Couldn\'t connect to mongodb, is the "mongo" process running?</p>';
    exit();
}
echo("<br>");
var_dump($db);
```

My output:

```
start1.7.4
Client created
object(MongoDB\Driver\Manager)#1 (2) { ["uri"]=> string(249) "mongodb://user:password@cluster0-shard-00-00-tmugt.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-tmugt.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-tmugt.mongodb.net:27017/testDB?ssl=true&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&w=majority" ["cluster"]=> array(0) { } }
string(24) "0c0000001078000100000000" bool(true)
```

What I am missing? Why I can't select database?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a correct way: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-driver-bulkwrite.php

```
    <?php
//errror_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
echo "start";
echo(MONGODB_VERSION);
try
{
$client = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager(
    'mongodb://user:password@cluster0-shard-00-00-tmugt.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-tmugt.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-tmugt.mongodb.net:27017/testDB?ssl=true&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&w=majority'
);
$writeConcern = new MongoDB\Driver\WriteConcern(MongoDB\Driver\WriteConcern::MAJORITY, 1000);
echo("<br>Client created");
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
    echo "***Client failed*** " . $e->getMessage();
    exit();
}
echo("<br>");
//var_dump( $client->getConnections() );
echo("<br>Client: ");
var_dump($client);
echo("<br>");
var_dump(bin2hex(\MongoDB\BSON\fromPHP(['x'=>1])));
var_dump(class_exists('MongoDB\Driver\Manager'));

$bulk = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite(['ordered' => true]);
$bulk->delete([]);
$bulk->insert(['_id' => 1]);
$bulk->insert(['_id' => 2]);
$bulk->insert(['_id' => 3, 'hello' => 'world']);
$bulk->update(['_id' => 3], ['$set' => ['hello' => 'earth']]);
$bulk->insert(['_id' => 4, 'hello' => 'pluto']);
$bulk->update(['_id' => 4], ['$set' => ['hello' => 'moon']]);
$bulk->insert(['_id' => 3]);
$bulk->insert(['_id' => 4]);
$bulk->insert(['_id' => 5]);

try {
    $result = $client->executeBulkWrite('db.collection', $bulk, $writeConcern);
}
catch (MongoDB\Driver\Exception\BulkWriteException $e) {
    $result = $e->getWriteResult();

    // Check if the write concern could not be fulfilled
    if ($writeConcernError = $result->getWriteConcernError()) {
        printf("%s (%d): %s\n",
            $writeConcernError->getMessage(),
            $writeConcernError->getCode(),
            var_export($writeConcernError->getInfo(), true)
        );
    }
    // Check if any write operations did not complete at all
    foreach ($result->getWriteErrors() as $writeError) {
        printf("Operation#%d: %s (%d)\n",
            $writeError->getIndex(),
            $writeError->getMessage(),
            $writeError->getCode()
        );
    }
}
catch (MongoDB\Driver\Exception\Exception $e) {
    printf("Other error: %s\n", $e->getMessage());
    exit;
}

?>
```